# How to launch Window with Chrome.Windows API - WindowState Locked-fullscreen?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The window gets created with fullscreen, but doesn't with locked-fullscreen. I need to get an extension to load in a state that prevents the user from closing it. Documentation says locked-fullscreen is available only to allowlisted extensions. Our organization allows extensions by default and configures the blocklist via Google Admin, so what am I missing here?

```
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("application.html"),
    type: "popup",
    state: "locked-fullscreen"
  }, function(win) {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the documentation here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/

You can do it by making sure **state** is **fullscreen**

```
chrome.windows.create({url: url, focused:true, state:"fullscreen", type:"panel"}, function(win) {

            
});
```